# "Expand" a webview into an android activity

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, view, webview

I have an android activity with some graphical elements likes button, textfield, progress bar etc...
I have also an invisible ("gone") webview that I want appears and "expand" OVER all elements of the activity when I call loadUrl() (when the page is loading).
The activity has a Linear Layout.
Is is possibile? How?

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

thank's to all

Comment: Ok I have a correct ImageView. 
But Using Relative Layout and trying to move elements,the app crash!
Using Frame Layout all is ok but I don't know how move the elements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of linearlayout, you need to use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout. Both offers overlapping. Or you can just wrap your linearlayout with any of them.

[RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <LinearLayout/> // your compontents, use gone to show webview
   <WebView/>      // use visible, vice-versa
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you use visible after calling loadUrl??

Comment: now all about webview is ok, but I have another problem.
Using relative layout and moving elements using graphical tool, app crash!
But if I use relative layout without move elements, app works!